# Order of Evaluation in c++

Tags: c++

i have just started in c++ so not sure about the order of evaluation.
In the below code segment as you can see changing the order of evaluation in evaluating C gives me different results when i am evaluating C*(line-i)/i , it gives me -131213633 and when i evaluate it as (line-i)/i *C , it gives me 145422675. I understand in the first case , it is an overflow issue but i want to understand the order of evaluation.

```
C = C * (line - i) / i ;
(gdb) p line
$1 = 31
(gdb) p i
$2 = 15
(gdb) p C
$3 = 145422675
(gdb) p C * (line - i) / i
$4 = -131213633
(gdb) p (line - i) / i * C
$5 = 145422675
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order flagged as off topic

Comment: Are you not sure what the order of evaluation is, or are you not sure why it matters?

Comment: @VaughnCato he stated that he knew that there were an overflow.

Comment: @Danh: True.  Are you saying that is related to my question?

Comment: @VaughnCato then the question is clearly about the order of evaluation only, thus an off-topic

Answer (score 0):

Both `*` and `/` associate to the left, so the expressions are evaluated left-to-right.

`C * (line - i)` (i.e. `C * 16`) overflows.
`(line - i) / i` is `1`, and `1 * C` doesn't overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout<< 3/2 *2; // Prints 2
cout<< 2*3/2;  // Prints 3
```

In the first line, 3/2 evaluates to 1.5, which is integer 1. Which then multiplied by 2 gives 2.

In the second line, the multiplication is done first, 2*3 evaluates to 6, which divided by 2 gives 3.

So when mixing integer and double arithmetic, the order of evaluation matters.